# Mostrar campo oculto en formulario en Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, xpath

Tengo el siguiente campo oculto que solo se muestra cuando tiene valor, pero quiero tenerlo visible siempre, he probado con un xpath pero no se si lo estoy cogiendo bien:

```
<field name="origin" attrs="{'invisible': [('origin', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='origin']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('origin', '!=', False)]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='origin']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">0</attribute>
</xpath>
```